# Como converter e salvar dados do DataGridView no banco Mysql

Tags: c#, mysql, datagridview

Tenho um campo no banco Mysql do tipo Double(10,2) e um grid onde o campo está assim:

> VALOR: R$10,00

Quando tento salvar da erro dizendo:

> A cadeia de caracteres de entrada não estava em um formato incorreto

Apontando para essa linha:

```
double col4 = Convert.ToDouble(dtgridprodutos.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value); // Valor Unitário
double col5 = Convert.ToDouble(dtgridprodutos.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value); // Valor Total
```

Vejam que estou convertendo o valor que vem do grid para o mesmo tipo definido no banco! Aguem pode me ajudar?

```
try
{
     if (dtgridprodutos.Rows.Count > 1)
     {
         ConectarBanco.Open();
         for (int i = 0; i <= dtgridprodutos.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
         {
             int colV = Convert.ToInt32(CodigoVenda.CodVenda_);
             int col1 = Convert.ToInt32(dtgridprodutos.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value); //Id
             string col2 = dtgridprodutos.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString(); //Descrição
             double col3 = Convert.ToDouble(dtgridprodutos.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value); //Quantidade
             double col4 = Convert.ToDouble(dtgridprodutos.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value); //Valor Unitario
             double col5 = Convert.ToDouble(dtgridprodutos.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value); //Valor Total

             MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand
                ("insert into itens_venda(cod_venda, cod_produto, descricao, qtd, valorunitario, valortotal)" +
                " values " +
                "(@cod_venda, @cod_produto, @descricao, @qtd, @valorunitario, @valortotal)", ConectarBanco);

             cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cod_venda", colV);
             cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cod_produto", col1);
             cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@descricao", col2);
             cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@qtd", col3);
             cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@valorunitario", col4);
             cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@valortotal", col5);
             cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }            
}
catch (MySqlException e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("ERRO" + e);
}
finally
{
    ConectarBanco.Close();
}
```

Comment: Que valor tem `dtgridprodutos.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value`? Vem com o **R$**? Penso que o problema será esse...

Comment: Sim, o valor exibido no grid está na forma curency "R$ 0.000,00" para ajudar o usuário na compressão, porém quando vou converter para o tipo duble aparece esse erro!

Comment: Você tem que fazer uma gambiarra, se só tem esse valor ai, retire o R$ com `replace`, retire o ponto, depois substitua a virgula por ponto, e retire os espaços. Isso já resolve o problema, como não tem tantas informações basicamente é isso. Você não pode converter direto, precisa colocar no padrão de número americano.

Comment: Então o caso é que não posso converter para Double strings que contenham Letras? Vou testar!

Answer (score 1):

Crie um método que lhe permita converter a `string` para `double`:

```
private double ConverteStringParaDouble(object valor)
{
    double dblValor = 0;

    string strValor = Convert.ToString(valor);

    strValor = strValor.Replace("R$", string.Empty).Replace(",", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator);

    if (double.TryParse(strValor, out dblValor))
        return dblValor;
    else return 0;
}
```

Depois evoque o método quando pretender passar a informação para a base de dados:

```
double col4 = ConverteStringParaDouble(dtgridprodutos.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value); // Valor Unitário
double col5 = ConverteStringParaDouble(dtgridprodutos.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value); // Valor Total
```

Basicamente removemos o símbolo "**R$**", substituímos a vírgula pela separador que está configurado nas Definições Regionais e convertemos para `double`, indicado corretamente pelo colega [@VirgilioNovic](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/54880/virgilio-novic).